# How can I recode this nested for loop counting box?

Tags: java

The goal of this assignment was for me to create a nested for loop that prints:

```
0 1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

While I have attempted the code myself on java, I was informed there was an issue.

I decided to use a third variable, x, which allowed the code to run okay but I was also told to redo the code without it. Try as I might to think of how that would work, I am stuck unfortunately

```
public class inputOutputExample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0; 
        for (int i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=4; j++) {
                System.out.print(x+ " ");
                x++;
            }
            x = x-3;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help redo the code only using i and j? I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You should strive to make your indentation nice and consistent- it helps you remember where you are in terms of nested { brackets }

Comment: It *might* be cheating, but I *might* do `IntStream.range(0, 4).mapToObj(i -> "0 1 2 3 4 5 6".substring(i * 2, (i * 2) + 7)).forEach(System.out::println);` - you don't even need two loops.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good thing that you tried by yourself, and actually solved the problem before asking for help.

You should start by implementing a nested loop that prints 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3.

Once you get this working, I believe it will be easy to change it so it prints 0 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean like this :

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(i+j+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an idle curiosity for you, here's how to do it with one variable. Don't hand it in- it's not what you've been asked for- but it highlights the use of divide and mod quite nicely:

```
for (int i=0; i < 16; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(i/4 + i%4);
```

It's essentially the same as my other answer, in that any number A can be thought of as the sum of "a smaller number B multiplied by C, plus the remainder of dividing the A by C"

Expressed in multiples of 5, 12 is 2*5 + 12%5

Hence for the 16 numbers you need to print, `i` could be provided by `x/4` (a sequence of 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3) and `j` can be provided by `x%4` (a sequence of 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)

Comment: That is a very interesting perspective, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

We can phrase your problem using two for loops.  The outer loop controls the starting value in each subsequence, and the inner loop controls the subsequence to be printed.

```
for (int i=0; i <= 3; ++i) {
    for (int j=i; j <= i+3; ++j) {
        if (j > i) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This prints:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Haha! Thanks both of you and everyone in the comments section for your time and extremely quick response. I swear I didn't just blindly copy before resubmitting... :>

Comment: @princepringles Is there any reason for unaccepting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using only two variables would mean doing an addition of the two:

```
    i j
0 = 0+0
1 = 0+1
2 = 0+2
3 = 0+3

1 = 1+0
2 = 1+1
3 = 1+2
4 = 1+3

2 = 2+0
3 = 2+1
4 = 2+2
5 = 2+3
...
```

Can you think of how to re write your loops now, to produce this set of steps?